# angular.filter groupBy and toArray and fuzzy

Tags: angularjs, group-by, fuzzy-search, toarray

I'm utilizing the following library in AngularJS... [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#collection)
and I'm trying to `ng-repeat` on the following structure.

[image]

When I combine all three directives... `groupBy`, `toArray: true`, and `fuzzy: search` I get the following screen shot...

[image]

If I use just `groupBy` and `toArray` I the page renders properly..

[image]

```
<div class="grid" ng-repeat="(key, items) in schedule[0] | toArray: true | groupBy: 'bid'">
    <div class="grid__column--12">
        <h3 class="barber-name">{{key}}</h3>
        {{key | json}}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__content">
                <ul class="list list--unstyled" ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <li class="list__item">{{item.name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above don't have the `fuzzy: search` which allows the page to render properly.

How can I make all three work together `groupBy`, `toArray: true`, and `fuzzy: search`?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with the following code...

```
<div class="grid" ng-repeat="(key, items) in schedule[0] | toArray: true | groupBy: 'bid' | searchField: 'bid' | filter: search">
    <div class="grid__column--12">
        <h3 class="barber-name">{{items[0].bid}}</h3>
        <!--{{key | json}} {{items | json}}-->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__content">
                <ul class="list list--unstyled" ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <li class="list__item">{{item.name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was missing the index `[0]` in the following line of code `<h3 class="barber-name">{{items[0].bid}}</h3>`